# ExtJS Ext.data.JsonStore loadData

Tags: extjs, jsonstore, loaddata

Can you help me solve the issue I'm running into with the loadData function as part of the Ext.data.JsonStore? I've created a basic example of the problem I'm running into:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Ext JSON example</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ext-all.js"></script>
<script>
    function example() {
        var exampleData = "{'exampleJSON' : {'exampleArray':[{'exampleID':1,'name':'Fred','description':'a guy'},{'exampleID':2,'name':'sue','description':'a girl'}]}}";

        var exampleStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            data: new Ext.data.MemoryProxy(exampleData),
            autoLoad: false,
            root: 'exampleJSON.exampleArray',
    fields: [
          {mapping: "exampleID", name: 'exampleID'},
          {mapping: "name", name: 'name'},
          {mapping: "description", name: 'description'}
    ],
            listener: {
                 load: function (oStore, ayRecords, oOptions ) 
         {
            alert('loaded successfully');
         }
            }
        });

        exampleStore.loadData(exampleData);  
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><button onclick="example();">Click for Example</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm running into is I'm getting this error reported by Firebug:
**obj.exampleJSON is undefined** 
This is likely being caused when I set the root as 'exampleJSON.exampleArray'.
Can someone help point out what I'm doing wrong?

(using ExtJs 4.1.0)

Thanks guys.

EDIT: to set this up, place ext-all.js and ext-base.js in a lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies, they were useful in sending me down the right path. I was able to get my original example to work by removing the 'data' field. I'm guessing it was causing conflicts when I tried to call loadData. Solution listed beflow

```
    function example() {
        var exampleData = {'exampleJSON' : {'exampleArray':[{'exampleID':1,'name':'Fred','description':'a guy'},{'exampleID':2,'name':'sue','description':'a girl'}]}};

        var exampleStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoLoad: false,
            root: "exampleJSON.exampleArray",
    fields: [
          {mapping: "exampleID", name:"exampleID"},
          {mapping: "name", name:"name"},
          {mapping: "description", name:"description"}
    ],
            listeners: {
                 load: function (oStore, ayRecords, oOptions ) 
         {
             alert('loaded successfully: ' + ayRecords.length);
         }
            }
        });

        exampleStore.loadData(exampleData);  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong in a number of places:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['exampleID', 'name', 'description']
});

function example() {
    var exampleData = [{
        exampleID: 1,
        name: 'Fred',
        description: 'a guy'
    }, {
        exampleID: 2,
        name: 'sue',
        description: 'a girl'
    }];

    var exampleStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'MyModel',
        data: exampleData
    });
}
```

Also, there's no ext-base file for Ext 4, so it's a redundant include.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I have to define a model? I was trying to avoid defining a model because the actual json structure I'm using is far more complex filled with nested lists and 60+ fields.

Comment: You can specify the fields inline on the store, but under the hood it just creates a model. Even if you do specify the fields on the store, it's not really any shorter to do so.

Comment: You should add the fields in the model, inside the config.